# Blank space after header.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm a complete novice at Wordpress. The question I'm asking might sound trite, but I truly don't know to solve this issue. The problem is that when I try to rescale the website homepage there's some blank space left after header.php - http://puu.sh/cqaZk/4aab65a78b.jpg. The issue doesn't persist on other pages.

Website:
http://vegankitchen.ru/

Nav code:

```
<!-- begin nav -->
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                    <nav>
                    </nav>
                </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
                <!-- end nav -->
```

Looking forward to the reply!

Comment: You should have a look at the css styles applied to elements in the header to figure out what's causing the extra space below. Without seeing a live site ( or a demo with the same problem ), its impossible to pinpoint the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I asserted the link to the main post.

Comment: If you mean the area where the picture of food is showing, that is because your entire header block `body > div > div.header-wrapper.home-background.clearfix` gets a fixed height set to it, probably via a javascript function. That seems intentional. If you want to get rid of it, you could either remove that part of the javascript code or set `height: auto !important;` via css styles.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, it didn't work out... but I managed to find the solution - I just changed <div class="header-wrapper <?php if(is_home()) { ?>home-background<?php } ?> clearfix" > to <div class="header-wrapper-home home-background clearfix" >. Don't know why, but it helped. Nevertheless, thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Glad you solved it. The difference seems to be that instead of `header-wrapper` it now has `header-wrapper-home`, which is probably a necessary class for the JS function to apply fixed height to.